# Concatenate TCHAR with char array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to receive the current directory of my project. After some time, I have found the function `GetCurrentDirectory` and it seems to work, but it only works with wchar_T, which to me, makes things a little more complicated.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    TCHAR pwd[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, pwd);
    MessageBox(NULL, pwd, pwd, 0);
    std::wcout << pwd + "\\filename.so" << '\n';
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to append additional text to the placeholder for the current working directory, however it does not work. What can I do to successfully get the current directory while also being able to append the name of a file in that directory? If possible, I would also like to be able to use `cout`, I mean why is the directory even stored as wide chars? All the symbols are valid as chars?

Oh, and I am using Visual Studio :)

Comment: What you're doing is adding two pointers together. Use `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: You should not use `TCHAR` stuff at all. Instead explicitly use `wchar_t` and corresponding variants of functions, such as `GetCurrentDirectoryW`. As for error it self you should output those string separately `std::wcout << pwd << L"\\filename.so" << L"\n";`. And don't forget to check return value of `GetCurrentDirectoryW` because not doing so may lead to situation when content of `pwd` is cropped or completely undefined.

Comment: @VTT Thanks. But is there any way to get the current directory as chars rather than wide chars? That would make it all so much easier

Comment: That would still require getting current directory path as wide chars and then converting it into utf8.

Comment: You can use GetCurrentDirectoryA() to move the clock back to 1992.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::wcout << pwd + "\\filename.so" << '\n';
```

In using the `+` operator, you are not concatenating two strings. Instead, you are adding two pointers together. What you need to do is abandon `TCHAR`s and char arrays. Instead, use `std::wstring` throughout.

Also, use the Wide (W) versions of the Win32 calls.

```
int main()
{
    wchar_t pwd[MAX_PATH];
    std::wstring finalPwd;
    GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, pwd);

    finalPwd.assign(pwd);

    MessageBoxW(NULL, finalPwd.c_str(), finalPwd.c_str(), 0);
    std::wcout << finalPwd + L"\\filename.so" << '\n';
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that you will constantly need to convert `wstring` to `wchar_t` and vice versa at API boundaries. But there is nothing you can do about that, except write some wrapper functions.

Comment: That does not work.. "No operator + matches these operands"?

Comment: Probably need to change `"\\filename.so"` to `L"\\filename.so"`

Comment: @Rocket Forgot to use the `L` in front of the literal. Now it should work

Comment: You can also use `wcscpy_s` to append to `wchar_t`

Comment: Oh perfect, thank you so very much! But do you know if I somehow can get the address as char rather than wchar_t? The reason why I ask is that I want to pass the address to SOIL (an image loader library), but that only accepts chars